# How to install a ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, colorize

I'm trying to write a program with colorized output. I looked at a few, and the gem I found was colorize. I've done some research, but I can't find step-by-step instructions on how to install a gem, require it, and use it. The gem I want is colorize, and I also need to know if there's anything else it requires. All I have is the standard ruby console that comes in the Ruby21 file, and notepad++ to write and save it. I need to know how and where to install it, whether I type something into the terminal or download a file and put it somewhere, and how to require it and its prerequisites(if any) in a file.

Comment: Check this out: http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the gem using your CLI simply by typing: `gem install colorize`. You can then utilize the gem by requiring it, so at the top of your .rb file add `require 'colorize'`. Then just test it out by trying `puts "This is blue".colorize(:blue)`.

Your `.rb` could look like this for example:

```
require 'colorize'

puts "This is blue".colorize(:blue)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the CLI? cause i've tried typing 'gem install colorize' into the ruby console and it gives me an error, something about unexpected tIDENTIFIER and expected 'do' or parentheses or brackets or something

Comment: CLI means "command line interface," which is not the same as the Ruby console. If you're on Windows, that would be the "cmd" program. On OSX or Linux, it's the terminal.

Comment: i tried typing it into command prompt and it said gem is not recognized as an internal or external command, blah blah blah

Comment: Here is a link of how to fix it: http://awordpress.net/blog/ruby-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-or-batch-file-error/

Answer (score -1):

Per http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/, you can install the colorize gem with the following command (in terminal or at command prompt):

```
gem install colorize
```

To list local gems, run this command:

```
gem list
```

And--by adding `require 'colorize'` to the top of the respective .rb file--that gem's lib directory will be added to your `$LOAD_PATH`.

Comment: when you say command prompt is that cmd.exe on windows or the ruby terminal in the ruby21 file?

Comment: On Windows, it's cmd.exe; on Linux/OSX, it's called the [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal).

Comment: i tried typing it into command prompt and it said gem is not recognized as an internal or external command, blah blah blah